# How to transfer my MySQL database to another computer?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I am using XAMPP package in my own desktop with Window 7 as OS.

That means I'm using MySQL DB and Apache server.

Now I would like to copy/migrate my whole MySQL DB to my friend's desktop, which is also with Window as OS, and also using XAMPP package.

Is there any way for me to do that?

Answer (score 56):

Copy database files from MySQL folder (under old **xampp** folder) except **share**,**bin**, and **script** folder see attached image to see which files need copy (only files with in green box) and replace all these database files in new installed **xampp** directory in MySQL folder.

Restart xampp start MySQL and open database and table to make sure its working.

[image: Files to replace in green lines]

Comment: Just what I was looking for, also add that, if windows dialog box comes up asking you if to replace some files with the same name, just click yes and continue. and also don't forget to stop MySQL and Apache and restart them.

Comment: awesome! But can't  we backup only specific a database ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes.
You can use the command line tool [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Saving your database

```
mysqldump -u[yourusername] -p[yourpassword] --all-databases > mydump.sql
```

Reading it back in:

```
mysql -u[yourusername] -p[yourpassword] < mydump.sql
```

I'm assuming the mysql bin directory is accessible via command line. [yourusername] and [yourpassword] should be written without the brackets.

Answer (score 4):

go to this address http://127.0.0.1/  and next phpmyadmin 
select database 
and click in export and select column ...
and click on go

copy file to server and goto phpmyadmin in server and click on import and add file database 
and enjoy it .

Comment: that's would be time wasting if you have many databases

Answer (score 1):

*A.Aleem11*'s answer will technically work but is a little too cautious and copies files over that don't contain any data or config information and are only relevant for the previous installation.

The answer is actually a lot simpler:

1. Make sure Apache and MySQL are turned off
2. In your new XAMPP installation, delete the `mysql\data` and `mysql\backup` folders
3. Copy the `mysql\data` and `mysql\backup` folders in your old XAMPP installation to the new installation
4. *(Optional)* If you have any config files in your old `mysql` folder (files that end in the `.cfg` extension and have the gear icon), copy these too. Chances are that if your MySQL installation is relatively recent you will have none of these, config files seem to be relied on less in modern versions.
5. Turn Apache and MySQL back on and navigate to `localhost/PHPMyAdmin` to confirm that all your database tables are present

Answer (score 0):

The datadir defaults to something like `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data`

You can just zip that folder and unzip it in the new server (with mysql server shut down in both servers) in the same place, and start mysql server there. This assumes that your datadir setting is the same in both servers.

Answer (score 0):

Given solutions didn't work for me. These are the steps solved my problem -

1. copy `xampp/mysql/data/ibdata1` from old installation to new installation
2. copy all databases folders except `mysql`, `performance_schema`, `phpmyadmin` from `xampp/mysql/data` and put them in new installation

Hope it helps.