# Move MySQL database from one PC to another

Tags: mysql

I am using xampp with windows 7, and I would like to copy a MySQL databse from C:\xampp\mysql\data to another PC, because I cannot access it from phpmyadmin, knowing that old PC shutdown unexpectedly and that caused a problem.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860118/how-to-transfer-my-mysql-database-to-another-computer) but it did not work.

Comment: Can you access it via console and use mysqldump?

Comment: let me try that one

Comment: can you guid me plz how to use mysqldump

Comment: You may dump a database using phpMyAdmin but it is safer to use mysqldump if you can.

Comment: @Dave I can not use phpMyAdmin , I can not use I am getting an error of #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engi

Comment: Then you should modify your question and remove the phpmyadmin tag.

Comment: @Dave thank you for your answer, I dont need to use phpmyadmin, so I need to copy physical database to another drive if it is possibel

Comment: Is it only one database or several databases?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p databasename > dbbackup.sql
```

Then to restore:

```
mysql -u root -p databasename < dbbackup.sql
```

The options are as follows.

- `-u` indicates the username (here I am using root - the administrator user, but you can use another user with rights to the database)
- `-p` indicates the prompt for a password (this is the password that is associated with the user you specified above). After pressing enter on the mysqldump command, you will be prompted to enter a password.
- `databasename` is the name of your database of course
- `dbbackup.sql` is the name of the file to save your exported database to (you can rename it to whatever you want

Notice in both commands the difference between `>` and `<`. These are redirection operators.

`>` indicates that you are writing to a file. `<` indicates you are reading from a file. You don't want to accidentally use `>` for the last command because you could end up writing over your backup file.